# Problem routes Children in angular with simple component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with routes in angular 8,  the problem is the routes in children its not working

my routes are:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin', component: MainComponent, children: [
      { path: 'uno', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'sub' },
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'sub' },
      //{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'sub' },
    ]
  }
];
```

The url localhost:5001/admin  is working  the components "MainComponent" and "HomeComponent" show in the browser,  but the url localhost:5001/admin/uno no, in the console i have a messege  " Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin/uno'"

Thanks in advance

** update **

I have this in the app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in the main.component.html

```
<div id="content" class="content">
    <div>
      <button routerLink="uno">Tab1</button>
    </div>
    <router-outlet name="sub"></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Comment: post also your MainComponent html and your HomeComponent html

Comment: Howcome your `outlet` is set to `'sub'`?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos Done! I have edited the question

Comment: @Passersby I have edited the question with the router-outlet (both)

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions for your issue. First if you want to use named outlets your link must look like this:

```
<button [routerLink]="[{outlets: {sub: ['uno']}}]">Tab1</button>
```

Second solution (preferred in this case I think) would be to remove the name from the `<router-outlet>` and from the path configuration. As you have a nested router-outlet in your MainComponent in route `/admin` all child routes will be rendred in the router-outlet of the MainComponent. Possible you have to add `pathMatch: 'full'` to your child routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "admin",
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "uno", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    ]
  }
];
```

```
<div id="content" class="content">
  <div>
    <button routerLink="uno">Tab1</button>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Fussel, but is not working , the problem is not the router-outlet is a children in the routes.

Comment: @VhsPiceros then you should update your question, because then I do not get what you are trying to achive